# Como encontrar um letra em uma string?

Tags: string, ruby

Como posso testar se uma letra (guardada em uma variável) esta contida em uma palavra?
ex:

```
palavra = "palavra"
escolha = "a"
```

## output

> A palavra tem 3 letras "a" na palavra....ou

Comment: Olá Eliezer, poderia nos mostrar o que você está tentando fazer? Um código iria ajudar muito a comunidade a te ajudar.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Não sou um grande fã de RegEx, mas Ruby incentiva não tendo uma solução muito simples para isto e ter sintaxe específica para expressões regulares, então acho o mais adequado.

```
palavra = "palavra"
escolha = "a"
contagem = palavra.scan(/(?=#{escolha})/).count
puts "A palavra tem #{contagem} letras 'a' na palavra"
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/SGNsgk). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lxmanras-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/StringOcorrences.rb).

Answer (score 2):

Um formato bastante legível seria utilizar o [array de caracteres](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-chars) que qualquer String oferece unido com um [`count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count):

```rb
lookup_char = 'a'
'abcd abc ab a'.chars.count {|c| c == lookup_char} # => 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser só saber se inclui a letra:

`"palavra".include?("a")`

Se quiser a quantidade de vezes que aparece:

`"palavra".count("a")`